# examining if a matrix is diagonizable

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

I was practicing some linear algebra problems and I stopped at this one:

Without calculating the eigenvectors, show that the following matrix is
diagonalizable and find the diagonal matrix to which it is similar.

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 1 & 4 \\
0 & 2 & 6 \\
0 & 0 & 5 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

How could I know the if its diagonalizable or not without calculating the eigenvectors?
Please help, I'm studying for tomorrow's exam.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint - It is a $\;3\times 3\;$ matrix with $\;3\;$ different eigenvalues

Comment: 3 different eigen values means it's diagnoalizable, right ?
i was going to do that but i wasn't sure about it

Comment: Yes it does because eigenvectors belonging to distinct eigenvalues are linearly independent.

Comment: Corrected Git. Thank you.

Comment: what about finding the diagonal matrix :D ? !!

Comment: @Mr. Cat, having the eigenvalues that already is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

The characteristic polynomial is $(x-3)(x-2)(x-5)$ as you can see directly from the matrix. This is also the minimal polynomial.
A matrix is diagonalizabe iff its minimal polynomial is a product of distinct linear factors. The diagonalization has the same diagonal as the original matrix.

Answer (score 0):

The given matrix is an upper triangular.We know that determinant of an upper triangular matrix is the product of its diagonals.Thus clearly characteristic polynomial is $(x-3)(x-2)(x-5)$ and so it has $3$ distinct eigen values.Now if a $n\times n$ matrix has $n$ distinct eigen values then it is diagonalisable.

Hence given matrix is diagonalisable.